# NodeJS: Adding items to a collection with one unique and one duplicate value

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a case where you have a collection for a group of people:

```
let collection = [];
```

My intent is to add "John" multiple times within this collection as there are two people with that name, as such I add a unique hash each time `collection.push()` is called. However, when I attempt to do so:

```
collection.push({
    hash: crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex'), 
    person: 'John'
});
```

The result is that only the hash gets updated, but the amount of objects within the collection stays the same: a single entry for John.

How would I be able to add the two or more Johns within this collection?

Comment: `push` method is for arrays and not for object. Ex: `const collection = []` `collection.push({
    hash: crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex'), 
    person: 'John'
});` And then in the array you can have multiples person with the same name but different `hash` key. If you want to use object, you can set `hash` keys for `collection` object and for every `hash` key have and object with person detail. Ex: `collection[crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex')] = { name: 'John' }`

Comment: you want o push persons in array ? or to db ?

Comment: Ah, I accidentally used the wrong brackets indeed. Edited the OP to reflect this.
Currently the target is an array, it's a small project I feel doesn't need a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works for me:

```js
let collection = [];
collection.push({
    hash: crypto.getRandomValues.toString('hex'),
    person: 'John'
});
collection.push({
    hash: crypto.getRandomValues.toString('hex'),
    person: 'John'
});
collection.push({
    hash: crypto.getRandomValues.toString('hex'),
    person: 'John'
});

console.log(collection)
```

Comment: I had just tested this within my source code as well and indeed; it works as it should. The error I made was to not look at the right log file where the array was outputted correctly, in the console I only outputted the newly created item causing my confusion. Apologies for the trouble!